# How to set carry flag in specific bit in GPR without shifts / rotations?

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, carryflag, eflags

I'm writing a program in NASM for Intel 80386 processor and i need to set the value of carry flag in a specific bit in GPR (general purpose register) without changing other bits in register.

Are there any possibility of doing so without using shifts/rotations of any kind?

Comment: `JNC skip; OR gpr, 2^bit; skip:`. Clear the bit if needed.

Comment: Which instructions do you consider to be “shifts/rotations of any kind?”

Comment: @fuz SHR, SHL, SAR, SAL, ROR, ROL, RCR, RCL

Comment: @MaxAzatian Any specific reason why you want to avoid these? What about other shift-like instructions like `bts`, `bt`, `btc`, `btr`, `shlx`, `shrx`, ...?

Comment: @fuz i have already the solution with rotation, but as a practice i would like to write the same program, but without rotations/shifts.
By the way, all BTx instructions get the value from bit and set it to the CF, but i need right the opposite : set CF in bit.

Comment: @MaxAzatian This is important because you can e.g. do `jnc skip; bts datum, bit; skip:` if the number of the bit is not a constant.  This avoids having to use one of your forbidden bit shifts.

Comment: "set the value of carry flag in a specific bit in GPR" -- there is only one carry flag, not one per register.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Code Golf questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One branch-free way of doing this would be to fill a scratch register with the carry flag, mask for the bit you want, then or it with your target register.

Using `EAX` as scratch (taking this as 32-bit values being manipulated):

```
sbb eax, eax
and eax, 1 << 16  ; Adjust bitshift in constant for the desired bit. Multiple bits can be used.
```

If the carry flag is unset, `sbb` will do `eax = eax - eax = 0`. If the carry flag is set, `sbb` will do `eax = eax - (eax + 1) = -1`, so all bits are set. The desired bit(s) is/are then masked in.

After that, you need to set the appropriate bit(s) in the target. If the bit is in an initial known state, this could be simplified. Using `EBX` as target:

```
and ebx, ~(1 << 16)  ; Same value at before. This doesn't need to be a shifted bit, it could be a number.
or  ebx, eax
```

---

Depending on what previously happened to the scratch register (`EAX` here) it might be worth looking at some optimization information like https://www.agner.org/optimize/. Some processors will recognize that the new value of `EAX` doesn't depend on the old value, some will see it as having a (false) dependency on that old value.

After looking at it, the document "Optimizing subroutines in assembly language" mentions the above `sbb` trick in the section "Replacing conditional jumps with bit-manipulation instructions".

Using `EAX` (the accumulator) as the scratch register will result in smaller code size.

Comment: sorry for not specifying, will fix it rn. 
I'm writing a program for Intel 80386.

Comment: Also consider using `cmovc` to shorten the critical path latency.

Comment: `sbb eax,eax` depends only on CF (not the old value of EAX) on AMD Zen / Bulldozer / Jaguar (https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf).  But on other CPUs (including all Intel), it does have a false dependency.  You might consider `xor eax,eax` / do whatever that sets flags / `setc al` / `shl eax, 16`. (Or if you can't zero a register ahead of the flag-setting, `mov eax,0`, but that risks partial-register stalls on Intel P6 family.) But if you have a reg that's probably "cold", SBB / AND / OR is probably good, 2 fewer uops than xor-zero/setc/shl/OR on CPUs with 1-uop SBB (post-HSW)

Comment: Some cases might be able to `cmovc` to select between two bit-positions for `bts`, if there's a bit you know is already already set.  (Intel has single-uop `bts`; on AMD it costs 2 uops IIRC)

Answer (score 4):

## Predictable Case

If the value `CF` assumes is highly predictable, use a conditional jump and code like this:

```
    ... operation that sets CF ...
    jnc   nc           ; skip setting bit if CF is clear
    or    eax, 1       ; set bit in eax
    jmp   end
nc: and   eax, ~1      ; clear CF in eax
end:
```

## Unpredictable Case

If branchless code is desired (e.g. because the value of `CF` is hard to predict or if this is a cryptographic application), consider using a conditional move.

### Computing CF is on the Critical Path

Assuming we would like to set the least significant bit in `eax` to the value of `CF` after performing some operation:

```
    mov    ecx, eax    ; make a copy of eax
    or     ecx, 1      ; set CF in the copy
    and    eax, ~1     ; clear CF in the original
    ... operation that sets CF ...
    cmovc  eax, ecx    ; set eax to ecx if CF was set
```

This code has more instructions than that in [Thomas Jager's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218519/417501), but its critical path latency is shorter, assuming computing `CF` is on the critical path but computing the prior value of `eax` is not.  Whether it's actually better depends a lot on the circumstances.

Neverthless, the simple variant

```
    and     eax, ~1    ; clear CF in eax
    ... operation that sets CF ...
    adc     eax, 0     ; add carry flag to eax
```

is probably best for this specific case (set least significant bit to `CF`) as it avoids two µops while having the same critical path latency.

### Computing EAX is on the Critical Path

If on the other hand computing `eax` is on the critical path but computing `CF` is not, Thomas Jager's solution is good, but it needs to be tweaked to clear the least significant bit of `eax` beforehand so the bit is cleared if `CF` was clear.